# DB2 query seems to hang

Tags: java, linux, database, db2, db2-luw

our platform is:

DB2 ESE 10.5.8 running on 
IBM Power Linux Power 7 with 
Red Hat RHEL 6.9 (Santiago)

The issue is: Sometimes certain requests get kind of "hung" because they don't seem to do anything yet they are still connected for hours (if not forced before) and don't release the thread which causes batch jobs to never finish until these requests are forced off.

There are NO locks of any kind (lock timeouts or deadlocks).

[db2top locks screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q145h.jpg)

[image: db2top application details]

These pictures show a complex query probably coming from a dbvisualizer but sometimes the query is just a "Select current schema from sysdummy1;" and yet never finishes.

Applications connecting to the database are Websphere Application Server (WAS) 8.5 and dbvis (dbvisualizer). Issue happens on both but more often with dbvis.

The application is in uow waiting state, that is, it should be waiting for work once previous work was completed.
On the other hand, I have not explained how such connections cause batch-jobs to never finish because that is exactly what I don't know and wish to know.

In other words: an "UOW Waiting" state application doing currently nothing but waiting shows an unfinished query running, which is a paradox.

Here you can see also UOW completion status is Committed, which I understand this app-handle has no commit-pendings pending.

```
Application Snapshot
Application handle                         = 47954
Application status                         = UOW Waiting
Status change time                         = 10/29/2018 09:40:02.391805
Application code page                      = 1208
Application country/region code            = 0
Application name                           = dbvis
Connection request start timestamp         = 10/29/2018 09:38:33.022561
Connect request completion timestamp       = 10/29/2018 09:38:33.023248
Application idle time                      = 6 minutes 14 seconds
Previous UOW completion timestamp          = 10/29/2018 09:40:02.079211
Elapsed time of last completed uow (sec.ms)= 0.001282
UOW start timestamp                        = 10/29/2018 09:40:02.390511
UOW stop timestamp                         = 10/29/2018 09:40:02.391793
UOW completion status                      = Committed - Commit Statement
Workspace Information
Most recent operation                      = Static Commit
Most recent operation start timestamp      = 10/29/2018 09:40:02.391735
Most recent operation stop timestamp       = 10/29/2018 09:40:02.391793
Statement type                             = Static SQL Statement
Statement                                  = Static Commit
Statement start timestamp                  = 10/29/2018 09:40:02.391735
Statement stop timestamp                   = 10/29/2018 09:40:02.391793
Blocking cursor                            = NO

Statement type                             = Dynamic SQL Statement
Statement                                  = Fetch
Section number                             = 163
Cursor name                                = COL_DYNH
Statement start timestamp                  = 10/29/2018 09:39:57.544068
Statement stop timestamp                   = 10/29/2018 09:39:57.545429
Blocking cursor                            = YES
```

Comment: Are there uncommitted transactions on any of those connections, or are the connections just idle?  You have not explained how such connections that you say hold no locks can cause batch-jobs to never finish.  Sounds like you have more than one problem. Depending on your license for Db2, consider configuring WLM (or other tooling) to force off idle-connections.

Comment: The application is in uow waiting state, that is, it should be waiting for work once previous work was completed.
I have not explained how such connections cause batch-jobs to never finish because that is exactly what I don't know and wish to know.

In other words: an "UOW Waiting" state application doing currently nothing but waiting shows an unfinished query running, which is a paradox. 

By being in UOW completion status = Committed, I understand this app-handle has no commit-pendings going, despite of which it does never finish, I don't know why.

Comment: "UOW waiting" means the Db2-server is waiting for the application to ask Db2-server to do something. Normally this means the applcation (e.g. dbvisualiser) is idle and "UOW committed" means there are no outstanding transactions.  Those idle connections are unlikely to be related to the symptom you mention that batch-jobs "never finish". Idle connections from dbvis are not  part of the WAS connection pool. You give no facts about the batch-jobs that "never finish", whether they are WAS jobs (or not), or what they are doing.  INSUFFICIENT INFORMATION.  Basic problem determination required.

Comment: As I commented before Apps connecting to the db are WAS and dbvis (dbvisualizer). 
Issue happens on both but MORE OFTEN with dbvis, i.e. this happens with dbvis much more frequently than it does with WAS. 
The example I am attaching is a dbvis example. 
Last week I had a WAS case and the batch job didn't finish until I forced a query that should take 2-3 seconds after 50 min of doing nothing (no rowsread, no rowswritten)
db2diag.log & db2inst1.nfy show nothing. There are no lock waits. The app is in UOW waiting but doesn't release the last operation.
What more info can I provide you with?

Comment: If the batch-jobs are WAS jobs, and if they are failing to complete, then show *evidence* of what they are doing when they are stuck, use WAS logs and db2diag.log to find evidence.  That is basic problem determination. LOOK FOR SYMPTOMS in diagnostics file of the apps,WAS, Db2 and analyze them.

Comment: I would look for newwork timeouts and the above.  If its a long really long querry the network might timeout before results are available.  Then once one thread is stopped its only a mater of time before you have created and in house DOS on your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is dbvis in auto-commit mode?

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/IMSupport/entry/In_DB2LUW_why_a_session_with_status_UOW_Waiting_holding_locks_and_log_space?lang=en

Comment: Thanks a lot, Paul !! You solved the issue !! Exactly, that was it. dbvis WAS NOT in auto-commit mode. I have been able to reproduce the issue by setting auto-commit off and inserting one row into one table. Immediately db2top shows select current schema from sysibm.sysdummy1 as a never-finishing query holding 4 locks (it has nothing to see, though, but that's another story). If I set auto-commit ON this does not happen. Neither db2diag.log nor the logs at the client side show anything relevant. Again, thanks a lot for your help !